# Use comment symbol in variable value TCL

Tags: tcl

I am looking to use the # symbol which is the symbol to indicate that everything following is going to be a comment in a variable value.  So, I would like to write the following:

```
set Dev1_Number 1#
set Dev2_Number 2#
```

But the program only recognizes 1 and 2 as values that can be placed the memory location of the variable.  Is there anyway to get around that?

Comment: Are you sure? Tcl is accepting the hash in the variable for me.

Comment: Does your # symbol appear in orange?

Comment: Orange? No, I'm running it through shell, so there's no colour styling. What output do you get after setting these variables? Tried using `puts $Dev1_Number`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl comments only occur when the comment character is the first character of a command word
(http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M29). You'll see code with end-of-line comments preceded by a semicolon

```
set foo bar ;# this is a comment
set foo bar  # this is an error!
```

That's not the case in your example. In your example, the hash is merely data.

Your comments indicate your editor is making an incorrect assumptions about Tcl syntax. What editor are you using?

If you are concerned, you can "force" the hash to be part of the value by using quotes

```
set Dev1_Number "1#"
set Dev1_Number {1#}
```

Comment: I was using notepad++.  It worked just like you and Jerry said.  The program I was using needed to be restarted.

Comment: Well, I haven't seen any good Tcl syntax highlighter yet. Notepad++ has a few quirks (esp `"` inside a regexp), but it works good enough for me.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You can escape the quotes (`\"`), it won't change your regex functionality and won't mess up the highlighting!

Comment: I know, but the cases where this happens are usually in other people code.

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash character, It escapes the original meaning of that character.

```
set a 3\#
puts "a=$a"


output: a=3
```